# using UIImageView in accessoryView in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am trying to use a custom image for the UIAccessoryView, however I can't seem to get it to work. When the table view launches, it doesn't update with any of the images. My code is the following:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *tableViewCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
    MenuItem *menuItem = [self.menuItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (!tableViewCell)
    {
        tableViewCell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
        tableViewCell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName: CaptionDistractionBodyFontName size: 15];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        tableViewCell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    }

    tableViewCell.textLabel.text = menuItem.name;

    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)tableViewCell.accessoryView;
    imageView.image = nil;

    if (menuItem.type == MenuItemTypeCheckMark)
    {
        if (menuItem.isCheckMarked)
        {
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DisclosureViewX"];
        }
    }
    else if (menuItem.type == MenuItemTypeSubmenu)
    {
        imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DisclosureViewArrow"];
    }

    return tableViewCell;
}
```

I've tried a lot of different stuff, i.e. calling `setNeedsLayout`, moving the code to a custom `UITableViewCell` in `layoutSubviews` and nothing seems to work. Aside from just creating a whole new accessory view myself, what is the correct way to go about this?

Comment: So your `UIImageView` isn't showing up at all?

Comment: Have you verified that the lines that actually set the `imageView.image` are being called? Have you verified that you actually have images in your resource bundle with those two filenames?

Comment: @rmaddy - yes to both

Comment: @hw731 - the imageView is there, but it just isn't updating with image

Comment: Did you set postion of image view on table view??? use custom cell

Comment: @QualityCoder - Yeah that's what I might have to do

Comment: You do not need to create a custom cell! This would be huge overhead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you initially setup the `UIImageView` with a `nil` image, the image view's frame has a zero width and height. You need to reset the frame after assigning an actual image.

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"DisclosureViewX"];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.image.size.width, imageView.image.size.height);
```

Edit:

Actually it would be even easier to call `[imageView sizeToFit]` after setting the image instead of setting the `frame`.

Answer (score 1):

try doing

```
tableViewCell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"DisclosureViewX"]];
```

Comment: This won't compile and certainly not work. `UIImage` is not a `UIView`.

Comment: That's how I had it initially Dylan, and it worked on iOS6 because when you do that layoutSubviews gets called again on the UITableViewCell. However, I don't think it's the best way because the same code doesn't work on iOS7.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that image view creates with zero size. Use initWithFrame: or initWithImage:, where image is not nil. After created with initWithImage:, image view will have bounds set to image size. A cell will center the accessory view automatically.